# Magento does not generate robots.txt

Tags: magento, robots.txt

I'm using `Magento ver. 1.9.0.1` and I'm having some trouble with `robots.txt`.

I set INDEX, FOLLOW on `system--> configuration--> design` but I can't find `robots.txt` file in the main directory.

I can't understand what is wrong...maybe I can set a robots.txt file by myself but I suppose it is better to let Magento make it.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have to create manually robots.txt in magento

Answer (score 0):

The setting which you are using will create the meta tag on every page as following

```
<meta name="robots" content="*" />
```

This setting will not create the robots.txt it self. You have to create robots.txt file by your self in Magento root folder.